# Crossdomain in AS3, want to display Google image search results

Tags: actionscript-3, cross-domain

I'm trying to make a flash program that displays google image search results. 
Since the results are all on different domains that I don't own, there is no way that I can do this through the normal crossdomain.xml procedure.

Does this mean that what I'm trying to do is impossible?
It works when you run it as a standalone application, not on a website.

I tried googling and found some methods on how to bypass it, but none of them work. Should I keep looking?

Answer (score 1):

You can load images from another domain without a crossdomain.xml file. You will get the error when you try to access the bitmapdata or try to modify the bitmap in anyway.

The following code works fine on the web.

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{

    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);


        var loader:Loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        loader.load(new URLRequest("https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTg2aSe9QhKeZrwNNM3Uyfstmsh24DWgH-Uhr-Xn-0lltyqhgvLRw"));
        addChild(loader);
    }

    private function onComplete(e:Event):void 
    {
        try {
            var bmp:Bitmap = e.target.content;  
        }
        catch (err:Error)
        {
            trace(err.message);
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: You can try what is being suggested here : 
http://www.inklink.co.at/blog/?p=14
It used to work for me at some point, but now when I try it I get a security error.

Answer (score 0):

As Baris mentions, if you're only displaying the data, you don't need a crossdomain.xml on the server hosting the images.
If you do need to access pixel data (copy/alter/etc.) you can try one of the following:

1. Use a server-side script to cache the image on a local server first, then load in flash.
2. Use an URLLoader to load the image as binary data, then pass the bytes to the loader class. Have a look at [Keita's article](http://labs.hellokeita.com/2011/12/02/editing-bitmapdata-from-different-domain/).

Here is the snippet from the post for reference:

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlLoaderComplete);

var url:String = "http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/product_mnemonics/50x50/flash_player_50x50.gif";
urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(url));

function urlLoaderComplete(e:Event):void
{
  var loader:Loader = new Loader();
  loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplete);
  loader.loadBytes(urlLoader.data as ByteArray);
}


function loaderComplete(e:Event):void
{
  var bmp:Bitmap = e.currentTarget.content as Bitmap;
  addChild(bmp);
  var bitmapData:BitmapData = bmp.bitmapData
  bitmapData.applyFilter(bitmapData, bitmapData.rect, new Point(0, 0),
    new ColorMatrixFilter([
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
      1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
      0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
      0, -1, -1, 1, 0
  ]));
}
```

Comment: Is this violating some sandbox law, which means that it might stop working in the future? If it is possible to bypass these restrictions this easily, why are they there in the first place?

Comment: Hmm, I've only tested the bytearray version locally(in Flash Player and AIR) so might've been sandboxed. If AIR is not an option, I'd say caching the image on a local server first then loading in Flash Player is your best bet.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought of that as a last resort, but it will be publicly available on the internet and I don't want a million images being throttled through my webserver...